# How to print all elements of an array one by one?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need some help in programming. I have a list that holds int numbers and I need to convert them to an array of strings and print them one by one all the elements. My code is all in the Update function and if I print an array in the Update function, it will run many times and will print many values. So I just need to somehow call a function that prints an array after a value has been stored or print all the values stored in the array at once.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PrintData: MonoBehaviour
{
    float tmp = 0;

    public List<int> CheckKeyPress = new List<int>(); //this is list that will 
    //have only 0 if user pressed key Z and only 1 if user presses key X. It will 
    //store in list 20 values (of 0 or 1).

    void Update()
    {
        // Here I check what did the user press after they hear some sound.
        tmp += Time.deltaTime;

        if ((Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Z)))
        {
            if (tmp >= 1) //I do this following someone's advice. Otherwise all 
        //this code wouldn't work in update function
            {
                CheckKeyPress.Add(0);
            }

            tmp = 0;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.X))
        {
            if (tmp >= 1) 
            {
                CheckKeyPress.Add(1);
            }

            tmp = 0;
        }

       //Here I want to make the array of strings from the list called
       //"CheckKeyPress ",and print all elements one by one. 

    }
}
```

I would like either to print the elements of array one by one (at the time they get store in lists) or to print them all after the list gets the all 20 elements.

Comment: Where do you want to print them? In the log? On the screen?

Comment: To print them in the log @Johnny

Answer (score 1):

You could use `string.Join()` to join all items from your `List<int>`, separating them by the specified separator:

```
Debug.Log(string.Join(",", CheckKeyPress.ConvertAll(x => x.ToString()).ToArray()));
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Where should I put this line? Because I included it in the update function and it is running so many times and also it gives values like: 0,1 whereas I want only 1 value each time I store to the list. @Johnny

Comment: It seems you want to print this line in update but only if key is z or x otherwise do not print... do you want to print only one element or all?

Comment: So let's suppose, the user pressed Z, in this case my list stores 0, At this time I need to put that in an array and print it. Or, the program waits till the user gets 20 elements and then print all the values. If there is any other way than to print in update, then is fine for me as long as it works.

Comment: Your list could have more then 20 items. What you have said seems that you want to move the print to `if` end `else if` and print the last end check after adding if count is 20 and then use line I have provided

Comment: My list will always have 20 int (0 or 1), I have wrote that in another script, whereas this script will be used to just store the values and I haven't wrote many lines here to simplify it but this is the idea and yes it will be ok to check in the end if the list have 20 values? then put those in an array of strings and print.

Comment: `Debug.Log(CheckKeyPress.Count == 20 ? string.Join(",", CheckKeyPress) : CheckKeyPress.Last().ToString());` [Join<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_Join__1_System_String_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__) makes it so you don't have to convert anything to string.

Comment: Thanks for your help @ArthurRey It does however give me an error in this part: string.Join(",", CheckKeyPress). The error is about CheckKeyPress and it says: Cannot convert from list<int> to string[]  Also I wanted to say that I do not want to join strings together into one (in case this code does). I would like to see in the debug log all values one after the other. I want to do that because after I put them in the array, I will send them to MySQL Database so every value will have it's own row. But for now I need to save them in the array.

Comment: @FK22 Either try `String.Join<int>(CheckKeyPress)` or use @Johnny answer `string.Join(",", CheckKeyPress.ConvertAll(x => x.ToString())`. We're concatenating your list of integers so you can see it in the debugger. Your list will still be available.